# It's about coding <%$ localizeByText: %> or <%: lang.GetTranslation %>

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm just beginner in coding. I would like to asking one question. For the `<div>` part, I need to insert the coding `<%$ localizeByText: %> or <%: lang.GetTranslation %>`. I put it on `<div>` title. But it's not working. Anyone?